# TextboxList issue for getting Json array

Tags: textboxlist

I am currently having problem in using the jQuery API for

[TextboxList](http://www.devthought.com/wp-content/projects/jquery/textboxlist/Demo/)

what i want is that to access the selected value in the Json array form, now the documentation suggest to use:

```
$('#form_tags_input').textboxlist();
```

but when i use it in the jQuery function on button click to get values using [getValues]
method it said undefined.

here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    // Standard initialization
    var t = new $.TextboxList('#SentTo', { unique: true, plugins: { autocomplete: { minlength: 2, onlyFromValues: true}} });
    //t.addEvent('bitBoxAdd', ContactAdded);
    //t.addEvent('bitBoxRemove', ContactRemoved);
    t.getContainer().addClass('textboxlist-loading');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetContacts',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (r) {
            t.plugins['autocomplete'].setValues(r);
            t.getContainer().removeClass('textboxlist-loading');
        }
    });

});

function GetValues() {
    var tblist = $('#SentTo').textboxlist();
    alert(tblist.getValues());        
    return false;
}

function ContactAdded(e) {
    //alert(e);
    //GetValues();
    return false;
}

function ContactRemoved(e) {
    //alert(e);
}
```

i am using GetValues() function on button click to getvalues.

A help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to made TextboxLists "t" variable global

The changed code is:

```
$(function () {
    // Standard initialization
    t = new $.TextboxList('#SentTo', { unique: true, plugins: { autocomplete: { minlength: 2, onlyFromValues: true}} });
    //t.addEvent('bitBoxAdd', ContactAdded);
    //t.addEvent('bitBoxRemove', ContactRemoved);
    t.getContainer().addClass('textboxlist-loading');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetContacts',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (r) {
            t.plugins['autocomplete'].setValues(r);
            t.getContainer().removeClass('textboxlist-loading');
        }
    });

});

function GetValues() {
    alert(t.getValues());        
    return false;

}
```